# Ionic v3 Remove Specific Keys from PLIST

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic3, cordova-ios

I'm working on an Ionic app which uses geolocation and based on my config.xml and an extra edit-config element, I'm getting the following three keys in my info.plist file:

- NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription : Location will be used while app is in use.
- NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription : This app requires constant access to your location in order to track your position, even when the screen is off or the app is in the background.
- NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription : This app requires constant access to your location in order to track your position, even when the screen is off or the app is in the background.

The LocationWhenInUse key is something I'm adding but the other two are coming in from somewhere else.  Here's my relevant config.xml:

```
    ...
    <platform name="ios">
        <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
            <string>Location will be used while app is in use.</string>
        </edit-config>
        ...
    </platform>
    ...
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^4.0.1">
        <variable name="GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Geolocation will be used to determine your location" />
    </plugin>
```

What I would like to do is remove the two "Always" permissions.  The only thing I want to ask the user is Never/When In Use.

Is there any way I can just remove the two "always" elements using the config.xml?  I don't want to have to remember to remove those two keys every time I do a production iOS build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These keys are [placeholders added by cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/blob/master/plugin.xml#L57).

The strings contained within `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` will only be displayed if you request to use location "Always" at runtime.

**Update**

To remove those keys from the `.plist`, you could use [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config). First install it:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-custom-config
```

Then add `<custom-config-file>` blocks under `<platform name="ios">` to delete the unwanted keys:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <custom-config-file parent="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist" mode="delete"/>
    <custom-config-file parent="NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist" mode="delete"/>
```

Comment: I understand but the requirement from the client is to only show the Never/While In Use options in the iOS settings for the app. The only way I have been able to get that to work is to manually modify the plist file in XCode and remove those two keys. When I do that, the Always option no longer appears. So it would be possible if I could just find a way to get the config.xml to automatically modify the plist (even if that means not putting the always keys in there to begin with).

Comment: if you use [requestLocationAuthorization()](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#requestlocationauthorization) to request location permission at runtime, you can explicitly request when in use mode and that will not show the Always option, even if the plist keys exist: `cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestLocationAuthorization(success, error, cordova.plugins.diagnostic.locationAuthorizationMode.WHEN_IN_USE);`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how I have done it. So when requesting permission, it only shows the when in use option. So that part is meeting requirements fine. When they got to Settings -> App name -> Location, they see three options, Never, When In Use, Always. They only want to see Never and When In Use in the options. If I remove the two keys from the plist, that's what shows up on the app location settings page. Does that make sense?

Comment: so you want to prevent a user from manually going into Settings and changing the Location Mode from When In Use to Always? seems like a way-out-there edge case, but you could remove those plist keys after they've been added using [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config) - I will update the answer to show how.

Comment: Yeah, believe me; I know I'm out on a limb when I'm googling and I can't find ANY examples! Lol, thank you sir; appreciate it.